# I want to createElement with click event but there is a problem

Tags: javascript, events

I need help for something in javascript.

The idea is I want to make new element by using createElement method and I want to add onclick property to this new element and I want if click on this element Implement function.

The code that I typed is as follows:

#### HTML

```
<a href="javascript:popupWin.crWindow()">open</a>
```

#### Javascript

```
var popupWin = {
                width: 640,
                height: 480,
                bg_colorBack: '#808080',
                content: "<div style='margin:0 auto; text-align:center; width:640px; heihgt:480px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); color:#000;'> Hello Wrold! </div>",

                crWindow: function(){
                    var winElem = document.createElement('div');
                    winElem.id = 'flywin';
                    winElem.style.backgroundColor = this.bg_colorBack;
                    winElem.style.direction = 'rtl';
                    winElem.style.textAlign = 'center';
                    winElem.style.width = '100%';
                    winElem.style.height = '100%';
                    winElem.style.position = 'absolute';
                    winElem.style.top = '0';
                    winElem.style.left = '0';
                    winElem.style.opacity = '0.6';
                    winElem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=60)';
                    winElem.innerHTML = this.content;
                winElem.onclick = this.closeWindow();
                    document.body.appendChild(winElem);
                },

                closeWindow: function(){
                    alert('hello');
                }
            }
```

Comment: first of all, I'd suggest using css ... if possible :)

Comment: @usoban - Thanks for your suggest but I want to use Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me the problem is that you're not assigning the click-handler - you're actually *calling* it.

```
winElem.onclick = this.closeWindow();
```

See those () there? They call the function, and what's assigned to onclick is the returned value. Since it returns nothing, the value assigned is `undefined`

This should make it work:

```
winElem.onclick = this.closeWindow;
```

Now it assigns the function itself.

However, with it like that, `this` will not refer to popupWin. If you want it to refer correctly, wrap the function in a closure like this:

```
var self = this;
winElem.onclick = function() {
    self.closeWindow();
};
```

Comment: Almost right, you are correct about the parameter list but not about `this`. At the time that the listener is assigned, this references `popupWin`, which is what the OP wants since `popupWin.closeWindow` is what should be assigned.

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure I follow? If he was to assign the function directly (as in the first example), `this` would be changed to point to `winElem` and not `popupWin`. In JS, `this` always points to the object a function is a member of (except in some special circumstances like when called via fn.apply or fn.call), which is why you need to work around it using the second approach.